# How to check AJAX Response String when type is set to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am using ajax to get JSON data from a web page. So I have set [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) to be `json`. If the web page processes the data successfully, it returns a valid JSON string, which is fine.

But if the web page fails, <strike>it returns a JSON string with error message inside</strike>, (sorry for the misunderstanding,) it returns an error string, not a json string, so JavaScript does not recognize it as valid JSON string. So if I check for `response`, it is null. In that case, I want to see the response string and check what the error message is.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.open("POST", "/someEndpoint");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.response);
}
```

([Fiddle to reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/h2xcg2cy/).)

If `/someEndpoint` returns valid JSON, `xhr.response` is a JavaScript object. However, if it's not valid JSON (as when the endpoint responds with an error message), then I get an empty object in `xhr.response`. I can't access the invalid-JSON error response, because accessing `xhr.responseText` gives the error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json')

I don't know how to read the original HTTP response after I've run the request with `responseType="json"`, since `responseText` cannot be accessed.

Comment: share your code or fiddle

Comment: have you tried to use `JSON.parse(responseText)` ?

Comment: Is your error in JSON format? if it is, it certainly would be possible to parse it. Otherwise, you'll have to read it as text (which is also possible)

Comment: *"it returns a json string with error message inside, so javascript does not recognize it as valid json string"* Uh? JSON is JSON. If JavaScript isn't able to parse it, it's not valid JSON to begin with. Maybe you mean that the response simply contains the raw error message?

Comment: @FelixKling I took some liberties and edited in a code sample that I think captures the OP's issue

Comment: @OP, I hope you don't mind I've edited your question with an example.

Comment: @KevinB I edited with an example; if you know of a way to access the original response body, or have general advice about how (not) to use `responseType`, I bet you could write a good answer `:)`

Comment: @apsillers, Thank you for the edit! That's exactly my issue. Anyway, if the web page failed, it returns an error string, so it is not in json format. I have access to the server side, so I could make it to return an error in a valid json type, but would like to see if there is another way before I change the server side code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your code the way it is currently this will not work as the error message directly indicates:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property
>   from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's
>   'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').

As you can see with the following proof:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//xhr.responseType = "json";

xhr.open("POST", "/echo/json/");
xhr.send("hello world");

xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.response);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

When you set the responseType to JSON you will not get a `responseText` property on the object. You will want to NOT set the `responseType` and evaluate the response (parseJSON) as a text string. If you have an error message for the response then your eval will fail to parse the JSON properly. This is alot like what jQuery does under the hood, and on that topic...

Why fight with the improbable task of working with the native XMLHttpRequest browser object. jQuery has spend years normalizing [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) across browsers and standardizing an API. That API has an 'always' call back that will fit your needs perfectly.

**TLDR** use jQuery for this and save the headaches.

Comment: Or, use text and parse it yourself.

Comment: Load jQuery (230.67 KB) to only solve an AJAX request doesn't make sense. It's preferable at least to use a lighter library specialized like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (13.9 KB).

Comment: @JérémieBoulay Yes there are various libraries to handle AJAX requests. `jQuery` is a very common library already found in most frameworks such as bootstrap and Wordpress and has great documentation and a large support community. I generally recommend based on these factors than the size of the library. Additionally, if a better option is available or preferred it is better to add an answer to the question instead of downvoting and dropping a comment on the accepted answer.